# Do jars behave differently in unix and linux?

Tags: java, linux, unix, executable-jar

I have a jar which creates a filtered XML file from a huge XML file.
Now this jar is working perfectly in UNIX with Java SE 1.5.0.15, but in Linux this jar is behaving differently and creating erroneous XML.

Can this be a platform issue?

Do I require to make a new jar for LINUX?

Comment: check what JREs/JDKs are installed

Comment: This is too vague. What is exactly the difference? What is "erroneous" about the XML created on your Linux system? What brands and versions of Unix and Linux are you using? Making a new jar for Linux is not the solution.

Comment: Java source code might be less universally portable than what you believe. You should show some of it.

Comment: It can be a bug to different version of the JRE (if you build and use your jar with jdk 1.6 under unix; and use jre 1.7 under linux). Same if you use diffent version of a library (xml parsing,...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can this be a platform issue?

Just a wild guess...In java the default charset is platform dependent. Default charset  depends upon the locale of the underlying operating system. When converting XML String to bytes  and writing them to a file you can get different results depending on the default charset.

byte[] xmlFileBytes = xmlString.getBytes() //depends on default charset

To see JVM default charset call `Charset.defaultCharset()` in your code on both platforms for comparison. Perhaps it is different on UNIX?
Annother way to determine default charset is to use command-line utility:
`$ jinfo <processId> | grep file\.encoding`
To see OS locale use comand: 
`$ locale`

XML files should be encoded in UTF-8 charset.
You can override default charset in your code with UTF-8: `xmlString.getBytes("UTF-8")`
Or you can override it by providing **file.encoding** system property when JVM starts:
`$ java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar your-jar-file.jar`

> Do I require to make a new jar for LINUX?

Probably not, Java mantra is supposed to be ["Write once, run anywhere"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_run_anywhere)

However:

> The catch is that since there are multiple JVM implementations, on top of a wide variety of different operating systems such as Windows, Linux, Solaris, NetWare, HP-UX, and Mac OS, there can be subtle differences in how a program may execute on each JVM/OS combination, which may require an application to be tested on various target platforms. This has given rise to a joke among Java developers, **"Write Once, Debug Everywhere"**.

Comment: Actually the problem was with locale setting in LINUX environment changed it to ISO-8859-1 and everything started working fine.
There were french characters in file which stopped JAR from processing.
Settings which i configured so that french and other types of characters could be read in environment were:
LANG=
LC_ALL=
LC_CTYPE=en_US.ISO8859-1

Answer (score 3):

Linux is a version of Unix. Do you mean Solaris?

I suggest you use the latest version of Java, and if you have to, the latest version of Java 5.0. I would also try with Java 6 update 45 or Java 7 update 25 to see if this is a bug which has been fixed.

Comment: Strictly speaking, Linux (i.e. GNU/Linux) is a "UNIX-like" operating system.

Comment: JAVA_HOME in UNIX(HP-UX) is set as java1.5/jre.
JAVA_HOME in LINUX is set as Java/linux-x86/j2re1.5.0_64/ provided that jar is working properly in 3 different UNIX machines using same version of java...!
I am not able to locate where the problem is?

Comment: We have a limitation that we have to use j2se 1.5 only!!

Comment: @Ba3ykaa I am aware that Java 5.0 was end of life'd about 5 years ago.  The reason I suggested it is to see if it may be a bug.  If the problem doesn't occurs with later versions, with the same code, it suggest a bug in the JVM.  If you can determine what the bug is, you can work around it. If it is a bug in your code, you can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

> Can this be a platform issue?

Potentially.  Or it could be a bug in the application you are running.

> Do I require to make a new jar for LINUX?

I doubt that will make any difference.  If the problem is a "platform issue", it is likely to be some incompatibility between the application (in the JAR) and the runtime libraries (in the execution platform).  Rebuilding the JAR is unlikely to alter that.

---

However, this is all guesswork.  Without more details (i.e. what the application is doing, and how it is "behaving differently") it is impossible to know what is going on, whether this is a platform issue (or just an application bug), and what you could do to fix it.